# How to connect to CloudantDB using spark-scala and read json documents in the form of a dataframe?

Tags: json, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, cloudant

Ive been trying to establish a cloudant connection using spark and read the json documents as dataframe, but facing issues in establishing a connection.

Ive tried the below code but it doesnt seem to establish the connection properties.

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Cloudant Spark SQL Example with Dataframe")
      .config("cloudant.host","ACCOUNT.cloudant.com")
      .config("cloudant.username", "USERNAME")
      .config("cloudant.password","PASSWORD")
      .config("createDBOnSave","true") // to create a db on save
      .config("jsonstore.rdd.partitions", "20") // using 20 partitions
      .getOrCreate()

    val dealDF: DataFrame = spark.read.format("org.apache.bahir.cloudant").load("trial_db")

ERROR: Error retrieving server response at https://null/trial_db
```

Please help me in understanding the issue here. Also is there any other way other than using this appache bahir?

ERROR:

```
Error retrieving server response at https://null/trial_db/_all_docs?limit=1.",
"thrown":{"commonElementCount":0,"localizedMessage":"Error retrieving
 server response at https://null/trial_db/_all_docs?limit=1.","message":
"Error retrieving server response at https://null/trial_db/_all_docs?limit=1.",
"name":"com.cloudant.client.org.lightcouch.CouchDbException","cause":
{"commonElementCount":61,"localizedMessage":"null: nodename nor
 servname provided, or not known","message":"null: nodename nor servname provided,
 or not known","name":"java.net.UnknownHostException","extendedStackTrace":
[{"class":"java.net.Inet6AddressImpl","method":"lookupAllHostAddr",
"file":"Inet6AddressImpl.java","line":-2,"exact":false,"location":"?"
```

Comment: can you post complete exception log ?

Comment: @Srinivas ive edited it with few lines of error.

Comment: spark version ? & add build.sbt file ??

Comment: spark version 2.4.1, "org.apache.bahir:spark-sql-cloudant_2.11:2.4.0" (using this dependency in bazel)

Comment: @ss301 can you try loading your database using sqlContext?

`val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val cloudantdata = sqlContext.read.format("org.apache.bahir.cloudant").
option("cloudant.host", "ACCOUNT.cloudant.com").
option("cloudant.username", "user").
option("cloudant.password", "password").
load("database-name")`

Comment: @ss301 here's a code snippet using `sqlContext` and easier to read: https://pastebin.com/A99KS1ax

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're trying to connect to a recently created Cloudant account using username and password, whereas the account is actually IAM-auth only. You can test this hypothesis by trying to talk to the database using `curl` and the credentials you use in your connector.

Cloudant accounts will default to IAM-only authentication. If you want to be able to connect using basic auth you need to explicitly state that you want "IAM + Legacy auth" in the dropdown on account creation.

Comment: No, I don't think that is the issue here. I was able to connect using a different method using basic auth. But it isn't working in this aspect. I have another iam account, so could test it. Is there a way to connect using iam and spark read?